# Explicit Intents-Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The aim is to get the text from edit view and display it in a `TextView` in another Activity on clicking a button.  My problem: as soon as I click the button the application stops.

Main.java:

```
package com.satish.explicitintents;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(Main.this, Second.class); 
            intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 
    }
}
```

Second.java:

```
package com.satish.explicitintents;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext"));
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.satish.explicitintents"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.satish.explicitintents.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.satish.explicitintent.Second"
                android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Stacktrace:

```
02-23 17:42:03.124: D/AndroidRuntime(4445): Shutting down VM
02-23 17:42:03.124: W/dalvikvm(4445): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.satish.explicitintents/com.satish.explicitintents.Second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.satish.explicitintents.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:28)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-23 17:42:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(4445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 17:42:24.654: W/KeyCharacterMap(4455): No keyboard for id 0
02-23 17:42:24.654: W/KeyCharacterMap(4455): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-23 17:42:25.904: D/AndroidRuntime(4455): Shutting down VM
02-23 17:42:25.904: W/dalvikvm(4455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.satish.explicitintents/com.satish.explicitintents.Second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at com.satish.explicitintents.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:28)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-23 17:42:25.924: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the xml layout also

Comment: Why you are asking same question again, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995813/explicit-intents-in-android

Comment: Could you please add a stacktrace?

Comment: post your XML file and error log.

Comment: you sure your EditText is not blank and you clicking the button? Post the log cat too.

Comment: and possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995813/explicit-intents-in-android

Answer (score 0):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.satish.explicitintents/com.satish.explicitintents.Second}; have
>   you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

The stacktrace suggests that you have not declared the activity in your manifest.

You got the package name wrong

Change to

```
 <activity android:name="com.satish.explicitintents.Second" 
 //explicitintents not explicitintent
```

Check

```
 package="com.satish.explicitintents"
```

Or just

```
 <activity android:name=".Second"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your manifest file. Replace the following lines-

```
<activity android:name="com.satish.explicitintent.Second"
  android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

with-

```
 <activity android:name="com.satish.explicitintents.Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Your package name is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the manifest file while specifying the path for the second activity. You need to use:

```
<activity android:name="com.satish.explicitintents.Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```